# Sticky header covering vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, html, header

My sticky header covers the vertical scrollbar, is there a way to fix this?

URL: http://jlwebdesigns.co.uk/

Header code (using a HTML5  tag)

```
header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #283744;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #4F5B66;
    height: 97px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Is that scrollbar for the maps `iframe` or the actual page? I don't see how you can overlap a scrollbar on a webpage, not sure it's actually possible.

Comment: Usee css :: header { margin-right : 20px; }

Comment: It's a scrollbar for the actual page. It occurs on every page regardless of the maps iFrame being there or not.

Comment: It cant be the browser scroll bar. Give us more code. Set up a JSFiddle.

Comment: link or it didn't happen. it must be iframe's scrollbar

Comment: Is this the problem? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/md9c8/). So the text is under the header. Thats whats happening in yours right? The map is half under the header?

Comment: http://jlwebdesigns.co.uk/

Here's a link to the error

Comment: Just seen it, its because you have `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body.

Comment: Thanks, Ruddy! How would I hide the bottom scrollbar without this error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

solution is not very neat but give `margin-top: 97px;` to the below div....based on **ruddy's** fiddle :

[here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/md9c8/2/)

Comment: You didn't got his question bro :)

Comment: Im just going to comment because you both did. **Rawr!** Also not sure what your doing in your answer.

Comment: See the `width`, it is overlapping the scrollbar

Comment: No, no! Its the fixed header sitting on top if the `div` (content) below it. The OP most probs has the `div` below the header set to `height: 100%;` with `overflow: scroll;`.

Comment: @NoobEditor yap, but am feeling lazy to make one, if he provides a fiddle I will answer

Comment: @NoobEditor Im going to guess this is the problem. Fix this and I think it will be right. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/md9c8/) Note how the text isn't there, because its under the header.

Comment: @Mr.Alien : okay lazy man...now i got that...damn..thought that its overlap at the edges!!! :)

Comment: @Ruddy : yeah..got it mate....u dont need to make me feel like a *even lesser than noob* !! :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien : `margin-top` is a solution...coz OP has fix height `header`...ur thoughts????

Answer (score 0):

Yeah make that element have a higher z-index and make sure you set a positioning such as relative or what not to that element.

```
header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #283744;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #4F5B66;
    height: 97px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Underlying element**

```
#underlyingelementwithscrolls{
position:relative;
z-index:1000;/*higher than 999 since header has it*/
}
```

in your case you have overlayed the bodies scroller 
do this and it should get fixed

```
body{
overflow:hidden;}
html{
overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Comment: please when you downvote an answer give reason to why?

Comment: ... maintaining equilibrium!! :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, however the underlying element is the webpage scrollbar.

Comment: @user3214729 have added a new solution for u

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your page you can change a couple of things...

Your banner is at 100% but it also has a padding which makes your banner to exeed the 100%. You try to avoid this by putting the overflow hidden in the html, body but that makes your header to overlap the scroll bar.

Solution:

```
html, body {
width:100%; 
overflow:hidden;  //remove this
}

#homeBanner {
width: 100%;
background: url(../img/bannerHolder.jpg) center no-repeat #558582;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 100px;
padding: 13% 2%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the site and a simple fix is to put:

```
margin-top: 97px; // if header has some padding so count that too.
```

Put that margin on the `section` in the CSS. This will fix the scrollbar but will break the logo. You will have to replace some stuff because of the new margin.

Here is a demo using the `margin-top`. You can see the text under the header. Take the margin away and it will hide behind the header.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/md9c8/3/)

**Note**: Just seen there's more then 1 section. You could just wrap them all in a div and give that the `margin`. Or use `:first-of-type`.